# I am struggling to link a SQL local server to my project

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am relatively new to c# and I am practicing adding databases to store my information. I cannot get the connection string to work for me. the code is :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename='C:/Users/joeco_000/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Telephone project/Telephone project/Database1.mdf';Integrated Security = True'");
```

I then have a button that will add the information to the database that is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" INSERT INTO Phon table (First,last,email,mobile,catagory) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + "' , '" + textBox3.Text + "' , '" + textBox4.Text + "' , '" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "')");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
```

I have taken this information from a tutorial that is 6 years old. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the error message received.

Comment: Firstly, don't use so old tutorials. Secondly, you need to learn to read the error messages. Those are very important in every programming language. You would quickly find out that you forgot to associate the command with the connection.

Comment: Also, before going any further read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and find more specific information on the subject. Frankly, that a tutorial shows you this way of using a database marks it as a terrible tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't associated the command with the connection before attempting to execute the query. One way to do this is:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)
```

Another way is:

```
 cmd.Connection = con;
```

Answer (score 0):

The name `Phon table` is not a valid table name. If your table really has a space in its name you need to surround it with square braces

```
INSERT INTO [Phon table] (First,last,email.......
```

Note that this is in addition to associating your command with your connection as the other answer indicates.